# Power AND Data on a SINGLE port with Adafruit PowerBoost 1000

Tags: raspbian-stretch, usb-power

I would like to be able to power my Raspberry Pi with the [Adafruit PowerBoost Charger1000](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2465) *and* use USB data while exposing only a single USB port on my device.

One idea I had was to simply split a USB cord between the Pi and PowerBoost. Routing the power pins to the PowerBoost and the data pins to the Pi.

Would this work? Would the USB data port on my Pi Zero operate with only the data pins connected, while drawing power from the PowerBoost module?

I should mention that my Pi is configured such that it already appears as a COM device and presents a terminal interface over COM when plugged into my PC.

Comment: *"Would this work?"* -> I think the only reason it wouldn't would be if the Pi port when operating as a slave only activates when there is current available on the power lines, which seems pretty unlikely -- the power and data shouldn't have much to do with one another.

Comment: Splitting the USB cord should work though you should keep the ground also connected b/w the Pi and USB cable to the PC

Comment: You mean the ground pin from my split USB cable should be attached to a ground pin on my Pi? Just to clarify.